# Tentacle/Octopack - Group Applications By Folder (Project Name)

Tags: octopus-deploy

I used to group related parts of my application like so:

Project Name

--Web UI

--Windows Service

--File Drop

"File Drop" is an example that might be related to both the service and the web site.

However, tentacle deploys each package separately, so with that I get something that looks more like (assuming ProjectName is used in the package id):

--ProjectName.WebUI

--ProjectName.WindowsService

How should I deploy a related shared folder?  Can you group applications in some way?  If not is there a recommended pattern to creating shared resources?

I should add that I'm using octopack.  I figure I certainly can manually put a nuget package together and use the relative dir parameters for IIS Sites and Services, but that starts to get more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [Custom Installation Directory](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Custom+Installation+Directory). This will let you control what directory the package is extracted to.

You can also do some custom setup in a deploy.ps1 file for each of your packages.

Comment: ugg, yup exactly.  Sorry, I think I'm still getting used to the Step form growing after you select the features at the bottom.

Comment: No worries. Took me a minute to get used to it too.